# In a row grid layout, how do you align headings that differ in number of lines?

Tags: grids

Have horizontal grid, and my headings vary in number of lines. No matter how I align the text it seems to either create too big of a gap, or break the grid. What's your preferred solution to this problem?

[image: Top align]

[image: Bottom align]

Comment: Looks at what other sites, particularly news sites as they have more things like this, do. The most common solution is to move the text to under the image. But the second way of doing it that you show isn't too bad

Comment: @ZachSaucier - Thanks! In this case I couldn't move the text under the image because they're dense scientific thumbnails that have no meaning without the title, so it helps the user read the title first. Will go with the second option!